# How to add Facebook SDK to Android Studio

Tags: android, facebook, import, sdk

I'm new to Android Studio. I have recently downloaded Facebook SDK. I'm not sure how to go about adding the files to my Android Studio project. I'm running Android Studio version 1.2.1.1 and I have Facebook SDK 4.2.1.

This is the first time I'm trying to import something into Android Studio.

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: I have the SDK files sitting in a zip folder on my Desktop. How do I add them to my Android Studio project so that I may use their classes and methods

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

You can just add this to your Gradle file like so:

```
dependencies { 
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
}
```

No need for the zip folder. More here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Comment: Which gradle file do I add this to?

Comment: build.gradle in the app folder. The link I gave you has picture instructions